# What version of Wildfly corresponds to EAP 7.2?

Tags: wildfly, jboss-eap-7

Again, no information is available about this on any Red Hat or JBoss site, so I ask it here...

I am not sure if it is 13 or 14.

Answer (score 6):

> Mapping the Community versions with JBoss EAP versions
>
> It is **not possible to map exactly** a version of the Community version
> (JBoss EAP, WildFly) with the corresponding version of the supported
> version (JBoss EAP) as they are **maintained in separated branches**. In
> general terms, the following tables summarizes the version of WildFly
> used as baseline for a JBoss EAP version:

JBoss EAP Version   WildFly Version

- JBoss EAP 7.4    WildFly 23
- JBoss EAP 7.3    WildFly 18
- JBoss EAP 7.2    WildFly 14
- JBoss EAP 7.1    WildFly 11
- JBoss EAP 7.0    WildFly 10
- JBoss EAP 6.4    JBoss AS 7.5
- JBoss EAP 6.3    JBoss AS 7.4
- JBoss EAP 6.2    JBoss AS 7.3
- JBoss EAP 6.1    JBoss AS 7.2
- JBoss EAP 6.0    JBoss AS 7.1

http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-eap/what-is-the-difference-between-jboss-eap-wildfly-and-jboss-as

Answer (score 1):

I believe that it is forked from WF 13.

If you look at the module for the server core, you'll see that WF 13 uses WildFly Core 5.0.0.Final.  EAP 7.2 Beta uses WildFly Core 5.0.5.

If you look at WF 14, it uses WildFly Core 6.0.2.Final, so EAP 7.2 is definitely not forked from this.

You can see the module used for the server core at: eap-install-dir/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/as/server/main

Answer (score -1):

The versions of JBoss EAP are forked from the Wildfly projects, when certain features are complete enough they fork the project and create an EAP version.

JBoss EAP 7.0 is forked from WildFly 10

JBoss EAP 7.1 is forked from a working branch of WildFly 11

JBoss EAP 7.2 unfortunatelly has no oficial information available yet as you can see [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.2.beta/html-single/7.2_beta_release_notes/index), [here](https://access.redhat.com/articles/112673#EAP_7) and [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.2.beta/html/introduction_to_jboss_eap/overview_of_jboss_eap#about_eap) - but I do believe it's forked from Wildfly 13 or 14, considering the last fork was Wildfly 11 and we are 3 versions ahead now.

---

And [here](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-eap/what-is-the-difference-between-jboss-eap-wildfly-and-jboss-as) is a comparative with some new information.